# Screen Support in Android 3.2 (API level 13)

Tags: android, android-layout, screen, android-screen-support

According to the note written in this documentation ([DeclaringTabletLayouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts)), the old groups was deprecated (small, normal, large, and xlarge), which is why we have to migrate to the new technique defined in Android 3.2.

> Note: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), these size groups are
>   deprecated in favor of a new technique for managing screen sizes based
>   on the available screen width. If you're developing for Android 3.2
>   and greater, see Declaring Tablet Layouts for Android 3.2 for more
>   information.

**How do we make different layouts for small vs normal vs large screens with the new technique?** I tried it and didn't find a solution, I want to set a different layout for each one, and the note said that is deprecated.

Old way classification :

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
```

New way :

```
320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).

res/layout-sw320dp/main_activity.xml # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

Comment: You should accept answers if you think that they helped to solve your problems. Some problems are hard and there are no perfect solutions, but even in such cases answers can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

It is well explained in the documentation that you can use it by creating `layout.xml` in values file, and creating aliases to point to alternative layouts. You can create values-large,values-sw-600, etc. and point to the layout alias you want to choose for that particular type.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
<item type="layout" name="login">@layout/login_large
</item>

 </resources>
```

Refer to http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html, as it explains well how to develop for multiple screens in the best way.

Comment: Thanks, but you have to use the old model clasification (no sw320dp format), it says "Therefore, you should also still use the abstract size bins (small, normal, large and xlarge) to be compatible with earlier versions". There is no way to distint between normal (426dp x 320dp) and large (640dp x 480dp) f.e. with the new technique. Other subject is that no exists much devices of that resolutions with Android 3.2 or upper.

Comment: have you read it in full?? -- you can avoid  it by putting all in just the layout file and providing aliases to use which layout ie for large,sw-600 you can use the same layout by creating the values file for both and pointing to the same layout

Comment: Yes, but with large is the old model clasification previus to Android 3.2

Comment: yap and it wont be taken and alternatively sw ll be taken by 3.2 + and ofcourse you can point both of them to a single layout but you ll have to provide both (you can use the large classification along with sw<> and the efficient way is also explained in that tutorial)

Comment: ok, but my question is for select distint layout for normal (426dp x 320dp) and large (640dp x 480dp) with ONLY the new technique based in dps (only), without large/normal folder/alias

Comment: of course you can avoid those if you don't need to support devices bellow 3.2 no other way