# Android (Studio): Smaller screens issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I've seen a lot of topics on development for various Android phone screen sizes. I've read about all of the different development pages on this topic such as [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing) and [this one](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#SmallestScreenWidthQualifier), but I'm still experiencing problems.

**Using Android Studio**

So let me first recap everything that is in my head right now concerning the different screen sizes etc. Please add more that I should keep in mind.

1. You should always use DP(everything but text) and SP(text)
2. You should create/adjust layouts for different DP sizes
   (layout-sw480dp ...)
3. Images should be resized for different DP sizes
4. All DP screens can have different resolutions (ex. 480x800px could
   be ldpi, mdpi, hdpi)

Now, I've got 2 issues. Concerning #2 and #4, but they are / might be related to eachother. I've created a lay-out for my HTC One (m7) which is 1920x1080 xhdpi(320dp) and everything works fine and peachy on the device.

Issue concerning #2: I've created multiple layout directories (layout-sw240dp, layout-sw320dp, layout-sw480dp). When I select xhdpi or xxhdpi phones in the Preview Window it switches to 320dp and 480dp layout accordingly. However, when I select an *mdpi* phone, the preview again takes the 320dp layout... Does anyone have an idea on this issue?

Issue concerning #4: On a resolution of 1920x1080 320dp my layout works prefectly, but whenever I change resolution (both higher or lower but keep 320dp) things will go south. For example, when I scale down the resolution half of my app just falls off screen. I thought this would not occur when using DP and SP consistently, but obviously I was wrong.

If someone could help me out on this it would be muchly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following project structure, see the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more information.

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

So you would put your layout file in the respective layout folder.

Addressing issue #2: If your mdpi phone has a smaller screen than 600dp, it will use the layout in res/layout folder. Also, the Android Studio preview function might not always reflect the full truth. Try it on your emulator.

Comment: Isn't that deprecated as stated here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316549/screen-support-in-android-3-2-api-level-13 ... That's why I got the layout-sw<n>dp maps.

Comment: Thank you Marcus, I've did that so far but still there's an issue. For example my phone (xhdpi so sw320dp) has a resolution of 1920x1080, and another phone (xhdpi) has a resolution of 1280x720. And now my layout just falls off the screen. See my issue there? The phone gets the layout from the same layout-sw320dp directory because it's both 320dp, but it has a different resolution and dp/sp don't seem to do their job. Also tried on emulator (genymotion). Thank you for your help so far @Marcus

Comment: @Serellyn Are you positive that you've declared all **layout** sizes in dp, and **only the text** sizes in sp? As you describe your problem, without looking at any code, this seems to be the problem here. Also, try not to declare any definite values but use `wrap_content` as appropriate. It would also be easier to debug if you post some actual code in your questions.

Comment: @Serellyn I would like to add that I rarely, close to never, define my layout sizes in DP. Although it's more responsive than using pixels, defining height and width with `wrap_content` or `match_parent` tweaked with `weigh_sum` and `relative layout` ensures a more responsive design. This is my subjective opinion of course, as application design is not a single-lane, one-way-only process.

Comment: I've made a [screenshot](http://s11.postimg.org/w50f3if8j/android_issue.jpg) to show what goes wrong and here's my [layout](http://pastebin.com/Ft8LXBBY) and [dimensions](http://pastebin.com/2tH3dpRq). I hope you can help me out, thank you so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71079/discussion-between-serellyn-and-marcus).